# RegEx match text in between delimiters

Tags: regex

I need a regex that extract text inside a delimiter but I'm 
having problem extracting the value inside the delimiter [DATA n] and [END DATA]

Here's my regex

```
(?<=\[DATA\s+\d+\]).*(?=\[END DATA\])
```

Here's example data I want to match

Some text here

```
[DATA 1]
data one 
some more data
[END DATA]
[DATA 2]
data two
more data
data
[END DATA]
[DATA n]
more data 
data 
[END DATA]
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You appear to be using regular expressions features like lookbehind and lookahead when you don't really need them. Try:

```
\[DATA\s+\d+\](.*?)\[END DATA\]
```

There's only one capture group in this regular expression, `(.*?)`. After using this, the result you're looking for should be in capture group 1.

Note also that I've used the non-greedy `.*?` match that will match up until the *first* following instance of `[END DATA]`. Without this, if you use just `.*`, you'll capture everything up to the *last* `[END DATA]`.

Answer (score 6):

In regex, `[` text between `]` is called a character class, and regex engines will only match **one** of the characters between the brackets. You just need to put backslashes to make them literal:

```
(?<=\[DATA\s+\d+\]).*(?=\[END DATA\])
```

Comment: sorry I edited my my post, it should contain the \ for brackets. thanks. but still it does not extract the data inside the delimiter btw i'm using expresso

Comment: This worked great for me (?<=\[).*(?=\]) for text like: [TEXT]

Answer (score 6):

The dot special character doesn't match newlines by default. Make sure you are using **single-line modifier** for your implementation of regex, or use `[\S\s]*?` instead of `.*?`

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html and http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html for details.

Comment: Better to specify the single-line modifier inline using `(?s)` at the front.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely an option. I don't think that's supported by all regex implementations though. As far as I know, Javascript doesn't support that syntax. 

The question's not specific, so I just suggested something that should work in most (if not all) cases.

Comment: I want to extract all the data inside the delimiter and it should be multiline, yes I agree .*? is not do applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the \ to escape character.

```
\[DATA\s\d\]+([^\[]+)\[[^\]]+\]
```