# regex pattern matching any text between two strings

Tags: regex

I have some text like this.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="/test/data/" >
```

I want to write a regex pattern that matches any string between composition and template.

I tried **`composition(.*)template`**. But this does not seem to work.

Comment: Try `(.*?)` instead of (.*)

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697644/regex-match-text-in-between-delimiters it should give you a good start, however it does not cover the case where `page` is found within the xmlns parts.

Comment: @ Josh, please use the answers area for posting possible solutions.

Comment: How doesn't it work? Please provide some example input and expected and actual output.

Comment: @Denomales I've noticed people doing this lately. I think it's fear of rejection. You can get downvoted if you submit an actual solution that people don't like, but you can only get upvoted for a comment (or flagged, which virtually never happens).

Comment: @Denomales If you're not sure whether what you're suggesting would answer the question, you know it doesn't, or you're too lazy to type up a whole answer, just a comment makes sense.

Comment: @ Josh, True you can be downvoted if you post a wrong answer, but any lost  points are returned to your account if you delete the answer after it's been downvoted.

Comment: @Alan.. I have replaced page with template. Please have a look

Comment: Is this going to be implemented in C++, Java, PHP, Perl, GREP, etc?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ. I just want to create search pattern in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the regex engine to treat your scalar as a multiline string with the /m option; otherwise it won't attempt to match across newlines.

An example of what I described in C# would be:

```
    string data = "Your string";
    Regex statisticsRegex = new Regex(@"composition(.*)page", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Match match = statisticsRegex.Match(data);
    if (match.Success)
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No Match!");
```