# How to apply this regex? in php

Tags: php, html, regex

**How to apply this regex? in Php**
I have code

```
$a = "{temp}name_temp1{/temp}  Any thing Any thing {temp}name_temp2{/temp}";
```

I just need **name_temp1** and **name_temp2**

Any name inside {temp}**This**{/temp}

Thanks You

Comment: use preg_match_all so it doesn't stop after first occurrence, `{tempb[^>]*}(.*?){/temp}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match text in between delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697644/regex-match-text-in-between-delimiters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lazy quantifier:

```
{temp}         # look for {temp}
(?P<value>.+?) # anything else afterwards
{/temp}        # look for {/temp}
```

---

In `PHP` this would be:

```
<?php

$a = "{temp}name_temp1{/temp}  Any thing Any thing {temp}name_temp2{/temp}";

$regex = '~{temp}(?P<value>.+?){/temp}~';
preg_match_all($regex, $a, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach($matches as $match) {
    echo $match["value"];
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `\Q...\E` sequence here?

Comment: Why while a curly brace doesn't denote a special meaning!?

Comment: You did it but need to modify initial description as well.

Comment: Thanks you  for  reply

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex: [`{temp}(.*?){\/temp}`](https://regex101.com/r/2xikZf/1)

And you can use it in PHP like this:

```
$a = "{temp}name_temp1{/temp}  Any thing Any thing {temp}name_temp2{/temp}";

preg_match_all('/{temp}(.*?){\/temp}/', $a, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]); // Returns ['name_temp1', 'name_temp2']
```

## eval.in demo

Comment: Thanks you  for  reply